# Why does the 20.04 installer think that a plain linux raid is made up of 2 x /dev/sdb2 partitions?

Tags: system-installation, raid, 20.04, curtin

I've been trying to figure out this one for a few evenings now. I downloaded the 20.04 server installer, and tried to install it on a linux raid which I configured in the installer. This consistently failed.

I then jumped into a shell just after the installer started up, and manually created a linux raid (two disks / mirrored). The partitioning table of both `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` is a grub / boot partition on `/dev/sdX1` and a `/dev/sdX2` partition which takes part in `/dev/md0`.

Once the linux raid is up and running, i jump back to the installer and try to install Ubuntu on the existing raid. This fails as well.

The error I get is this :

`comparing device lists : expected ['/dev/sdb2', '/dev/sdb2'] found: ['/dev/sdb2', '/dev/sda2']`

I don't get that! Why does the installer expect that the linux raid should be made up of 2 x `/dev/sdb2`?

During some attempts, I've also seen `expected ['/dev/sda2', '/dev/sda2']`. It appears that the installer "randomly" picks a single partition that it expects to see twice - but that's just an observation (or speculation).

No matter how I try to install Ubuntu 20.04 on a linux raid, it fails. A regular install goes just fine.

[image]

Comment: Bugs are off-topic here.

Comment: @user68186 yes, but at the point of writing i did not know this was a bug. I answered my own question once i discovered it was a bug. Although your comment points out a true fact, its both too late and pointless. The question was already asked - and answered.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused by my disks having an invalid WWN number. The developers came up with a way to work around bogus disk WWNs. Great work!

https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1876848